# No access to dynamically allocated array of 2 dimensions

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, malloc

I'm experimenting with the dynamic memory allocation of variable sized arrays. The function "ft_ultimate_range" seems to work, however, a problem arises when I try to access and print the values of each array's array. It signals either segmentation fault: 11, when compiled with GCC, or "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector" with [http://pythontutor.com/c][1]. I understand that this has to do with the use- or abuse of pointers... ehm

```
// allocate a grid of [n][n] with numbers ranging max-min
int   *ft_ultimate_range(int **range, int min, int max)
{
    int len, *ptr;
    int count = min;

    len = max - min;
    ptr = range;
    // allocate memory **arr
    range = malloc(len * sizeof * range);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          range[i] = malloc(len * sizeof * ptr);
    }

    // assign values to allocated memory location
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
        range[i][j] = count++;
      }
      count = min;
    }

    // free memory **range
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      free(range[i]);
    }
    free(range);

    return ptr;
}

int main() 
{
  int n;

  n = 6 - 3;
  int **ptr, *arr;
  arr = ft_ultimate_range(ptr, 3, 6);
  // print 
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("%d", ptr[i][j]);
    }
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

...a little pointer in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Comment: 1. Function arguments are copied and assignments to that won't affect caller's local variables. 2. You cannot use freed buffer. If you want to let `main()` use buffer allocated in `ft_ultimate_range()`, do not free them.

Comment: @Spinkoo I do not understand your comment. The use of `sizeof` in the snippet looks fine.

Comment: It seems to work? "It signals either segmentation fault: 11" means it doesn't work. It's in fact thoroughly broken, starting with the signature.

Comment: @mch `ptr` and `range` are the same, but the sizes of allocated elements should not be the same. One is an integer and the other is a pointer.

Comment: @Spinkoo yes, it compiles: https://ideone.com/DTTw5Y

Comment: @n.m. `range[i] = malloc(len * sizeof * ptr);` is correct, changing it to `range[i] = malloc(len * sizeof(ptr));`, what I think Spinkoo suggested with his comment, will make it incorrect.

Comment: @mch no it is not. `ptr` is a pointer to a pointer to an `int`. `*ptr` is a pointer to an `int`. One needs `sizeof(int)`, not `sizeof(int*)` here.

Comment: @mch sorry my bad! I looked at `ptr = range;` and assumed they are the same type. In fact this assignment is incorrect, not the use of `sizeof`.

Comment: Consider [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it obvious you are quite lost regarding how to return an allocated grid (*pointer-to-pointer-to-int*) from `ft_ultimate_range()` to `main()`.

To begin, you do not need to pass `range` as a parameter to `ft_ultimate_range()`. Instead, make the return type `int **` and declare `int **range` within `ft_ultimate_range()` and then allocate `len` pointers, and then allocate `len` integers per-pointer, assign the values and then return `range` and assign it to `arr` in `main()`, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* allocate a grid of [n][n] with numbers ranging max-min */
int **ft_ultimate_range (int min, int max)
{
    int len = max - min,
        **range = NULL,
        count = min;

    /* allocate len pointers */
    range = malloc (len * sizeof * range);
    if (!range) {           /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-range");
        return NULL;
    }

    /* allocate len int per-pointer */
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        range[i] = malloc (len * sizeof *range[i]);
        if (!range[i]) {    /* validate alloation */
            perror ("malloc-range[i]");
            while (i--)             /* free previously allocated rows */
                free (range[i]);    /* free pointers */
            free (range);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    /* assign values to allocated memory location */
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            range[i][j] = count++;
        }
        count = min;
    }

    return range;
}
```

(**note:** you MUST VALIDATE EVERY ALLOCATION...)

In `main()`, you don't need `ptr`, all you need is the `int**` pointer you will assign the return from `ft_ultimate_range()` to, e.g.

```
int main (void) {

    int n = 6 - 3;
    int **arr;

    arr = ft_ultimate_range (3, 6);
    if (!arr)       /* validate return */
        return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf (" %d", arr[i][j]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
        free (arr[i]);
    }
    free (arr);

    return 0; 
}
```

(**note:** similarly, you must validate the return of `ft_ultimate_range()` before blindly looping through the values (that will not be there if an allocation failed)).

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/alloc_a_grid
 3 4 5
 3 4 5
 3 4 5
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/alloc_a_grid
==29026== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==29026== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==29026== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==29026== Command: ./bin/alloc_a_grid
==29026==
 3 4 5
 3 4 5
 3 4 5
==29026==
==29026== HEAP SUMMARY:
==29026==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==29026==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 60 bytes allocated
==29026==
==29026== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==29026==
==29026== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==29026== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
int **ptr, *arr;
arr = ft_ultimate_range(ptr, 3, 6);
```

`ptr` is NULL / uninitialised now. You cant allocate of this. `malloc` must be **before** call a function `ft_ultimate_range`. Here: `printf("%d", ptr[i][j]);` is `NULL[i][j]`.

And you free `**ptr` in function `ft_ultimate_range`.

Hope this help.

Comment: `ptr is NULL now.` Wrong. It is uninitialised.

Comment: This isn't the problem. The problem is that the pointer to allocated memory is not returned to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

```
int **ptr, *arr;
```

`ptr` is *uninitialised* at this point. It's value is *indeterminate*.

```
arr = ft_ultimate_range(ptr, 3, 6);
```

Passing an uninitialised value to a function is *always* wrong. If you hope the function will initialise it, you are mistaken. Read on [pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value).

```
ptr = range;
```

This assignment is wrong. You should have received a compiler warning about it. If you did not, upgrade your compiler ASAP. Never ignore warnings. Toying with a program that compiles with warnings is a waste of time.

```
for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  free(range[i]);
}
free(range);
```

At this point, every pointer in the program is invalid. Dereferencing them is undefined behaviour.

It isn't at all clear what your program is supposed to return. You are not using the return value anyway.

I suggest changing the signature of your function to this:

```
int** ft_ultimate_range(int min, int max)
```

Try to fit whatever you are trying to do in this mold.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not sure what you mean. How would you pass an ADT variable to a function? You normally cannot even create one in the caller. You pass a *pointer* to an ADT, and it should be initialised. Passing pointers to uninitialised memory around is of course OK. It's the pointer itself that must be initialised.

Comment: Ah now I understand, you mean that passing the uninitialized value of what's inside `int**` is always wrong, since the function can't do anything meaningful with that parameter. That's correct, of course.